# lmPerm p-values and multiple testing

Tags: r, regression, multiple-comparisons, p-value, permutation-test

I've started using [lmPerm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmPerm/index.html) in order to perform regressions in R. 
The equation I want to fit has the form:

```
out3 <- lmp(outcome ~  bin1 + bin2 + cont1 + cont2, perm="Exact")
```

Where "outcome" is a non-normally distributed continuous variable, and `bin*` and `cont` are binary and continuous regressors (similarly, they are non-normally distributed). Each variable has a length of approx. 110 cases.

Here are my questions:

1. This code works fine, but every time it runs in R, different p-values appear for each regressor. Which p-value should be reported in my results? I've tried repeating the test several times (in a loop) and getting an estimate from that, but I'm not sure it works...
2. If some of the predictors are changed and (then) several models / hypothesis are tested, should Bonferroni corrections be used in the same way they are applied for ordinary regressions? Is `lmp` somehow robust to multiple testing procedures?

Comment: Is this question *only* about how R implements this function? If so, it is probably better asked & answered on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) rather than here, if not, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. But no, my question is not about the implementation of the function. I put it here so that everybody could see it. 
As stated in the main post, my two questions are about 1) choosing a p-value after a regression using permutations, and 2) robustness of this procedure, and wheter or not (and how) Bonferroni corrections should be used. 
Regards,

Comment: This question needs to be separated into the two distinct questions contained within it: (1) Why can p-values vary between runs of a permutation test? (The answer, btw, is in the `lnperm` [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmPerm/vignettes/lmPerm.pdf) at the top of p. 9.) (2) How does one protect against multiple comparisons when evaluating alternative models and multiple hypotheses?

Comment: @whuber Your Q2 is what I was trying to ask: How does one protect against multiple comparisons when evaluating alternative models and multiple hypotheses? Any hints? 

Thanks!

Comment: If you would include that information in an edit, it will bring your post to the attention of current users, increasing your chances of getting a good answer.